# Disabling the javascript based on screen size

Tags: javascript

I have this code and I want to disable this one when my screen size turns to `766px`.

Can someone help me on this?

```
$("#menu-main-menu #menu-item-28").hover(function() {
    $('#menu-main-menu .sub-menu').css("display", "block");
    $("#menu-main-menu .sub-menu").hover(
        function() {
            $('#menu-main-menu .sub-menu').css("display", "block");
        },
        function() {
            $('#menu-main-menu .sub-menu').css("display", "none");
        });
    },
    function() {
        $('#menu-main-menu .sub-menu').css("display", "none");
    }
);
```

I found this one and I guess this ones could help in enabling the script, but I don't know how to apply.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > 766) {
        //script here
    }
});
```

Comment: You can hide the elements using CSS then you change screensize, see mediaquery https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the elements using CSS then you change screensize, see [mediaquery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Something like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    #menu-main-menu #menu-item-28,
    #menu-main-menu .sub-menu {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

or you can use the script you found

```
function onHover() {
    function() {
        $( '#menu-main-menu .sub-menu' ).css("display", "block");
        $( "#menu-main-menu .sub-menu" ).hover(
        function() {
            $( '#menu-main-menu .sub-menu' ).css("display", "block");  
            },
            function() {
            $( '#menu-main-menu .sub-menu' ).css("display", "none");
            });
    },
    function() {
        $( '#menu-main-menu .sub-menu' ).css("display", "none");
    }
}

var isLargeScreen = $(this).width() > 766;
$(window).resize(function() {

    var largeScreen = $(this).width() > 766;
    if (!isLargeScreen && largeScreen) {
        $( "#menu-main-menu #menu-item-28" ).on('hover', onHover);
    } else if (isLargeScreen && !largeScreen) {
        $( "#menu-main-menu #menu-item-28" ).off('hover', onHover);
    }
    isLargeScreen = largeScreen;
});
```

This is not a full working example, but you can see the logic and modify to also unbind hover for `$( "#menu-main-menu .sub-menu" ).hover(` which I'm not sure you are using correctly by passing 2 functions to it?

Comment: Hello, How can I hide the elements using CSS, do I need to call the function onHover() on CSS and make it display:none when the screen is 766?

Comment: No, the CSS mediaquery would it self monitor the screensize and the elements you want to be hidden will get the new CSS. Example:

@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    #menu-main-menu .sub-menu {
        display: none;
    }
}